# Teradata Find last 1 year using current date issue

Tags: teradata

I am using

```
CURRENT_DATE- INTERVAL '13' MONTH
```

to get 13 months data.
You see this returns a invalid date error. Because current date (March 29th) - 13 months is an invalid date ( Feb 29th 2015).

Dont we an inbuild function to fix this issue instead of writing some kind of a custom logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leap years are hell for `INTERVAL` math. Instead use `ADD_MONTHS()`:

```
ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -13)
```

`INTERVAL` is great for subtracting smaller units of time though.